# Generate token after doing a search in Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to generate a token just same as :

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.password)
        .then(data => {
            return data.user.getIdToken();
        })
        .then(token => {
            return res.json({token});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            if(err.code === 'auth/wrong-password'){
                errors.password = "Wrong Credential; Please try again."; // un-authorize
                return res.status(403).json(errors);
            }
            else if(err.code === 'auth/user-not-found'){
                errors.email = "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted."; // un-authorize
                return res.status(403).json(errors);
            }
            return res.status(500).json({error : err.code});
        })
```

In this scenario I will receive a token as soon as I login with correct username and password.
I want the same scenario (generating token), when I do a search on the database and I got success as follows :

```
db.collection('users').where('phoneNo', '==', req.body.phoneNo)
        .get()
        // .then(data => {
        //     let users = [];
        //     data.forEach(doc => users.push(doc.data()))
        //     return res.json(users);
        // })
        .then(data => {
            return data.user.getIdToken();
        })
        .then(token => {
            return res.json({token});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).json({ error : err.code});
        })
```

But here I am getting :

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getIdToken' of undefined`. Is there any way to generate this token and can using while routing to a protected path ?

Comment: I am unclear what you're trying to do here.  It doesn't look like your code is doing anything with the results of the query.  A Firestore query doesn't work like a Firebase auth sign-in.

Comment: I want to generate a token if I get a success on the query `db.collection('users').where('phoneNo', '==', req.body.phoneNo).get()`

Comment: Generate a token for what purpose?  Why is this required?  Why can't you use the token provided at sign-in?

Comment: I want to signIn using phoneNo and OTP. And I am not able to get the token what and how I generally receive from signInWithEmailAndPassword

Comment: Querying Firestore isn't going to sign the user in with their phone number.  There are different APIs for phone auth.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth